# Python Django Pagination and url.id

Tags: python, html, django

I have small problem here goes the code :

Html Code :

```
a href="{% url 'entertainment:novelsView' novel.id %}">buttonclass="pull-right btn btn-primary btn-xs">Link span class="fa fa-link"</span></button</a
```

view.py

```
    def novelsView(request,novels_id):
        novels=Novels.objects.filter(id=novels_id)
        context={'novels':novels}
        return render(request,"enter/novelsView.html",context)
```

apps = urls.py

```
    url(r'^novelsView/(?P<novels_id>[0-9]+)/$',views.novelsView,name="novelsView"),
```

Problem :

I am using pagination to view data all so, there is link which shows above: anchor tag to render to another page using id. Viewing is good but, if i click on pagination e.g:  << [1][2]>> 2 clicked then shows in `url : http://localhost:8000/enter/search/?page=2`

error:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /enter/search/
```

Answer (score 1):

you didn't need implement pagination. django framework help you to pagination.

use this tutorial:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/pagination/
and accroding to your django version, change version of this tutorial.